# Counting Records <1500 and >= 1500

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Concecptually, I'm completely fragged on what to do here as far as a query structure.  I've attempted to combine two qry's with a union all and the output is not what I wanted.

Below are the two tables and columns I need

account table: acct_no

amount table:
acct_no,
amount_id,
amt, 
date

What I want to do is count the number of records with <1500 and the number of files >=1500

it's so simple I'm sure, and I'm making it complicated

```
(
SELECT 
COUNT(acct_no) as GT1500,
Null as LT1500,
DATEPART(Year, amount.Date) Deposit_Year, 
DATEPART(QUARTER, amount.Date) Deposit_Qtr, 

 From account full outer JOIN amount ON account.AcctNo = amount.AcctNo
where amount < 1500 

group by
COUNT(amount.Date)as LT1500,
DATEPART(Year, amount.Date) Deposit_Year, 
DATEPART(QUARTER, amount.Date)
)

union all

(
SELECT 
Null as GT1500,
COUNT(acct_no)as LT1500,
DATEPART(Year, amount.Date) Deposit_Year, 
DATEPART(QUARTER, amount.Date) Deposit_Qtr, 

 From account full outer JOIN amount ON account.AcctNo = amount.AcctNo
where amount >= 1500 

group by
COUNT(amount.Date)as LT1500,
DATEPART(Year, amount.Date) Deposit_Year, 
DATEPART(QUARTER, amount.Date)
)
```

is this the best way to do this?  I'm getting one data set, but basically stacked on top of each other.  I want the data merged essentially....

UPDATE: "Case When" strikes again.  That's why I love this site, folks are there to pull you out of the weeds!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something a bit simpler like this?

```
SELECT sum(case when amount > 1500 then 1 else 0 end) as GT1500
    , sum(case when amount < 1500 then 1 else 0 end) as LT1500
    , DATEPART(Year, amount.Date) Deposit_Year
    , DATEPART(QUARTER, amount.Date) Deposit_Qtr 
From account 
full outer JOIN amount ON account.AcctNo = amount.AcctNo
group by DATEPART(Year, amount.Date)
    , DATEPART(QUARTER, amount.Date)
```

Comment: you don't need that WHERE clause

Comment: True enough. I just included it since it was in the original. I hadn't look that close, but it sure is silly when you look closely. :)

Comment: Go figure, a Case statement.  Thank you so much.  That totally works, with the where clause I get one less record. I think no where clause is what we need.  Thanks a million.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do what you're looking for:

```
SELECT amount.acct_no, count(amount.acct_no)
FROM amount
join account on amount.acct_no = account.acct_no
WHERE amount.amt >= 1500
GROUP BY amount.acct_no
HAVING COUNT(amount.acct_no) < 1500
```

Here is a simple [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f8828/6) demonstrating the concept (on a much lower scale)

Comment: ok, this gives me a result, but I'm looking for two seperate results <1500 and >=1500.  Sean's answers works.  Thank you for your assistance.